# How to import request module between html script tags?

Tags: javascript, html, module, request

right now I have a node.js file that imports the requests module using

`var request = require('request');`

However, when I put this in between script tags in my html, it logs,

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

How do I import the requests module between html script tags??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use browserfy

Run the terminal commands and it works!